# PHP Login Form In Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've started created a login form within a Bootstrap modal, I already have the code for the modal (simple bootstrap modal), and I have the PHP code to complete the login on a separate page (login.php), but I would like to have the login validate and return the errors inside the modal, possibly without refreshing the page. Here are examples: http://demo.flarum.org/#/ and https://phpacademy.org/, both have a login modal, and return errors as well as displaying a loading icon.

Here is my modal code with the form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalSignin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-signin">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title text-center">Sign In</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit">Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="text-center text-muted">Don't have an account yet? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

And here is the simple php code in login.php, (I know this code can be improved, but just as an example) that I would like to somehow attach to the modal.

```
 if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) && empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a username and password!';
    }

    else if (empty($username)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a username!';
    }

    else if (empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a password!';
    }

    else {

        $login = login($username, $password);

        if (!$login) {
            $errors[] = 'Couldn\'t sign you in with those details!';
            echo outputErrors($errors);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $login;
            redirect('index.php');
        }

    }

}
```

I might be doing a lot wrong, but if someone could point me in the right direction or show me some example code that would be great.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried AJAX?

Comment: I have heard that I could accomplish this with AJAX, but I have pretty much no idea how to go about it! any advice would be much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

As peterKA said, You need to use ajax, maybe through jquery to ease things out a bit. Do you have any knowledge in jquery? You can check out http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
a plugin that sends forms via ajax to the server with almost no modification of your code.